# Is a subset of $\ell^\infty$ metrizable?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

I need to apply Choquet's Theorem for an exercise. But Choquet has two versions of the theorem (a version for metrizable subsets and a version for non-metrizable subsets). In the metrizable case he says:

"Suppose that $X$ is a metrizable compact convex subset of a locally convex space $E$ and that $x_0$ is an element of X. Then there is a probability measure  $\mu$ [...]"

Here's the setting: $E=\ell^\infty$ and $X=\{a_n\in\ell^\infty |\ n,m\in\mathbb{N}\ b^ma_n\geq0\}$

**My Question:** Is $X$ metrizable and why is it compact ?

My first approach was using the facts that $\ell^\infty$ is not separable and $\ell^\infty=(\ell^1)^\ast$, but I didn't help so much.

Comment: Subsets of metric spaces are metrizable: simply restrict the metric to the subspace. Definition of $X$ is not clear. What is $b$?

Comment: To talk about metrizability and compactness you have to fix a topology first. These two questions are dependent, they cannot be treated separately. $a_n$ is a sequence, what does $b^ma_n\ge 0$ mean?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy  great answer thanks a lot! $b^m$ is just another sequence. You can interpret $X$ as the set of sequences $a_n\in\ell^\infty$ that aren't negative.  Can we use something like Banach-Alaoglu for the compactness ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment above $X$ is metrizable. If $(a_n) \in X$, not all $a_n$'s $0$,  then $\{(a_n),(2a_n),(3a_n),\cdots\}$ is a sequence in $X$ which has no convergent subsequence. Hence $X$ is not compact.